# Footer at the bottom where content overflows the footer

Tags: css

I have the page layout with footer still at the bottom of the page. The problem is when I use some divs with content which are FLOAT. If I ommit the float then the content behaves properly and does not overflow the footer.
Please see:

```
`enter code here`
http://jsfiddle.net/8o7t4wq9/1/


CSS:
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}

HTML:
<div id="container">
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="body">
       <div style="width:100%;min-height:500px;background-color:gray;clear:both;">IMAGES</div>
       <div style="width:30%;min-height:1500px;margin:5px;background-color:green;float:left">First box of content</div>
       <div style="width:30%;min-height:1500px;margin:5px;background-color:green;float:left">Second box of content</div>
   </div>
   <div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `footer{clear:both;}`

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer {
   position:absolute;//remove
   bottom:0;//remove
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
    clear:both;//add
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a parent div to your floated divs and add clearfix to the parent.

```css
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}

.clearfix:after {
 visibility: hidden;
 display: block;
 font-size: 0;
 content: " ";
 clear: both;
 height: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="body">
       <div style="width:100%;min-height:500px;background-color:gray;clear:both;">IMAGES</div>
       <div class="clearfix">
           <div style="width:30%;min-height:1500px;margin:5px;background-color:green;float:left;">First box of content</div>
           <div style="width:30%;min-height:1500px;margin:5px;background-color:green;float:left;">Second box of content</div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot, it works fine now (regarding the advice to remove the absolute position, I could not do that because if the content was shorter than the height of the page, then the footer would not sit down, but thanks anyway)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to pinpoint/see your problem widouth fiddle, but you should probably look at css clearfix

Add css class(clearfix) to containers

```
.clearfix:after{
    content: "";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}
```

for more info and cros browser support look at this thread [What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)

Comment: I have put the link to fiddle in my question, it is http://jsfiddle.net/8o7t4wq9/1/

Comment: you can see hov you can add clearfix to your code http://jsfiddle.net/mzvaan/53h36Lht/

Answer (score -1):

Remove `position:absolute` and `bottom:0` from `footer` and add `clear:both`.

```
#footer {
   width:100%;
   height:60px;
   background:#6cf;
   clear:both;
}
```

[Read More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)